# Prove or disprove - if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then $\sum_1^\infty f(1/n)$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove or disprove - if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then $\sum_1^\infty f(1/n)$ is convergent.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long while. Any direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

$f(x) = \frac x {\log(2/|x|)}$ if $x \ne 0$, $f(0) = 0$, is a counterexample.

Comment: How is f defined for $x<0$?

Comment: Sorry.  I fixed it so it is defined for $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks -- it's a nice example!

Answer (score 1):

If we can write
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(c)/2
$
where
$x \le c \le x+h
$,
then,
since
$f(0) = f'(0) = 0$,
by setting
$x=0$ and $h = 1/n$
we get
$f(1/n)
=\frac{f''(c_n)}{2n^2}
$
where
$0 \le c_n
\le 1/n
$.

Therefore,
if $f''(x)$
is bounded in
a neighborhood of zero,
say
$|f''(x)| \le M$
for
$|x| \le \epsilon
$,
then
$|f''(1/n)|
\le M
$
for $n > 1/\epsilon
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{n > 1/\epsilon} f(1/n)|
&\le \sum_{n > 1/\epsilon} |f(1/n)|\\
&= \sum_{n > 1/\epsilon} |\frac{f''(c_n)}{2n^2}|\\
&\le \sum_{n > 1/\epsilon} |\frac{M}{2n^2}|\\
&= \frac{M}{2}\sum_{n > 1/\epsilon} |\frac{1}{n^2}|\\
\end{array}
$

and this converges.

Comment: You don't know that $f''$ exists.

Comment: I'm assuming that it does, and that it is bounded in a neighborhood of zero.